# Select DB Schema before creating table in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In my project, I have to separated databases, which I set up like this:

```
// app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
#base
database_host: 127.0.0.1
database_port: null
database_name: nm_admin
database_user: nm_admin
database_password: 'nm_admin'
#user1
database_host_user1: 127.0.0.1
database_port_user1: null
database_name_user1: nm_user1
database_user_user1: nm_user1
database_password_user1: 'nm_user1'

// app/config/config.yaml
doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection: default
    connections:
        #default
        default:
            driver:   pdo_mysql
            host:     "%database_host%"
            port:     "%database_port%"
            dbname:   "%database_name%"
            user:     "%database_user%"
            password: "%database_password%"
            charset:  UTF8
        #user1
        user1:
            driver:   pdo_mysql
            host:     "%database_host_user1%"
            port:     "%database_port_user1%"
            dbname:   "%database_name_user1%"
            user:     "%database_user_user1%"
            password: "%database_password_user1%"
            charset:  UTF8
orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        #default
        default:
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
            auto_mapping: false
            connection: default
            mappings:
                AppBundle:  ~
        #user1
        user1:
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
            auto_mapping: false
            connection: user1
            mappings:
                AppBundle:  ~
```

Now, when I create an Entity for the databases, like this

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_clients")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\ClientRepository")
 */
class Client
{

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $mailbox;
}
```

with `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`
 it always puts it to the nm_admin database (the default one).
The docs for Doctrine do not say anything about selecting a schema, [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html) but is there a way? I want certain entities to belong to nm_user and some to nm_admin, how can I define that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to update the second db by this way:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force --em=user1
```

And have a look to: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

Comment: I think I understand. I have the "User" class (for nm_admin) and the "Client" class (for nm_user1) both in the "AppBundle/Entity" folder, do I have to move the "Client" class to a new Bundle, e.g. "UserBundle/Entity" and update the mappings?